# Asp Net core Controller URL parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I have `Controller` `class` like this:

```
namespace OptionsAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class OptionsController : Controller
    {    
        HttpGet("{symbol}/{date}")]
        public IActionResult Chain(string symbol, string date)
        {
            DateTime quotedate = System.DateTime.Parse(date);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to call the chain function through the URL like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/options/Chain/symbol=SPX&date=2019-01-03T10:00:00
```

I get this error:

> FormatException: The string 'symbol=SPX&date=2019-01-03T10:00:00' was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index '0

It seems like "SPX" and the "date" are being concatenated as one `string`. What is the correct way to call this `URL`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The given route template on the action

```
[HttpGet("{symbol}/{date}")]
```

along with the template on the controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

expects

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/options/SPX/2019-01-03T10:00:00
```

But the called URI

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/options/Chain/symbol=SPX&date=2019-01-03T10:00:00
```

maps the `Chain` in the URL to `symbol` and the rest to `date`, which will fail when parsed.

To get the desired URI, the template would need to look something like

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class OptionsController : Controller {

    //GET api/options/chain?symbol=SPX&date=2019-01-03T10:00:00
    [HttpGet("Chain")]
    public IActionResult Chain(string symbol, string date) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Reference [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing)